# How to add item to SharePoint dictionary variable SPD

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, directory

**Question:**

Is it possible to use a SP directory variable like a array in other programming languages?

**Problem:**

I have e workflow where I get tasks from a SP list (`Call HTTP Web Service`) and like to save all the tasks that passed a specified `dueDate` (Item attribute) in the items to directories that get created for the tasks owners.

At the moment I have a loop that loops all the items I get from the list, and i have a condition that checks for the `dueDate`. So I only need to know if/how i can directly create directories and add date to them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding items to a dictionary is an all-at-once kind of thing, so you have to know all of your dictionary properties at the time that you create it.